# keyboard bindings broken

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I've managed to get the keyboard bindings super-a and super-f broken...

They now respond as if I long-press super without a or f (open the launcher).
I don't know how to restore the default working where it opens the applications dash or files/folders dash.

I've tried to run "unity --reset" but that didn't make any difference accept that also ctrl-alt-t (terminal) also doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem myself by booting to single user, remove and purge unity, unity-place-applications and unity-place-files and afterwards reinstall them.
Now everything is back in order.

Answer (score 1):

Open Ubuntu Software Center and install Compiz.
Open Compiz (alt + F2 and type ccsm).
Go to Unity and check the shortcuts.

Comment: Compiz should be installed already. You just need ccsm.

Comment: compiz and compizconfig-settings-manager were already installed...
Opening the settings manager didn't help, even resetting my profile to default (within ccsm) doesn't help.
The combination alt-f2 also doesn't work btw...